# WordPress Custom Post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I create WordPress custom post type and show post by taxonomy here is code

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'financial_news', 'tax_query' => array( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'news_category', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'pakistan' ) ), 'posts_per_page' => '7');
$query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts()) :
        $count = 0;
        while( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

When code is run it show all posts, but I want to only show those post that are in Pakistan
how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you could use Simple Taxonomy Query as depicted on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

so it should look something like this

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'financial_news', 'news_category' => 'pakistan', 'posts_per_page' => '7');
```